# Lookup HTML fragments with known CSS properties

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, getcomputedstyle

I'm looking for some kind of "reverse CSS selectors": Given a HTML document how is it possible to look up fragments that have a specific formatting? For instance I would like to get a list of segments that use bold text (`font-weight: bold;`). Given this document:

```html
<h1>example</h1>
<p>This is <b>an example</b> with <span style="font-weight: bold">formatting</span>.
</p>
```

The list of segments would then include (for instance given via XPath selectors):

- `/h1[1]`
- `/p[1]/b[1]`
- `/p[1]/span[1]`

Comment: @Rob Sure it is not! I thought there might be some Browser API, programming library, algorithm etc. to do the lookup. It turns out [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is the answer!

Comment: I see I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to loop through all the `elements` in the DOM and check the `font-weight` of each `element`:

```
window.getComputedStyle(myDOMElement).getPropertyValue('font-weight');
```

A font-weight of `400` is normal (in CSS, `font-weight: normal` and `font-weight: 400` are identical) so any `font-weight` above `400` means that the element is bolded.

**N.B.** In CSS, a `font-weight` is usually either `400`, `700` or `900`.

Once you have identified a bolded `element`, you can apply an identifying `class` to that `element`.

**Working Example:**

```js
const allDOMElements = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (let i = 0; i < allDOMElements.length; i++) {

  let fontWeight = window.getComputedStyle(allDOMElements[i]).getPropertyValue('font-weight');

  if (fontWeight > 400) {

    allDOMElements[i].classList.add('is-bold');
  }
}
```

```css
.is-bold {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
<p>This is <b>an example</b> with <span style="font-weight: bold">formatting</span>.
</p>
```